# File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, ob-scala

Tags: org-mode

After upgrading to emacs 27

```
brew install emacs --HEAD
```

I get this on startup

```
    $(which emacs) --daemon
    ...
    Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/Users/username/.emacs.d/init.el’:

    File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, ob-scala

    To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace. 
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `ob-scala.el` was removed in Org 9.0.10: https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/90986a8e2fe881105cc6d869a7592581520646d2

It is now included in the [`scala-mode`](https://github.com/ensime/emacs-scala-mode) package on MELPA.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that emacs-scala-mode has removed `ob-scala` as `ensime` (that it depends on) is abandoned:

- https://github.com/hvesalai/emacs-scala-mode/issues/155